# Would a 1.2GHz, 1GB RAM tablet run a graphical browser under Linux?

Tags: linux

I want to install Linux on a tablet. The specs are:

- 1.2GHz CPU
- 1GB RAM

It just needs to run a graphical browser which will run a local django application, probably writing data to an SQLite database.

Does this sound reasonable, or is the tablet too low-specced?

**Edit:**

The django app will be running on the tablet too.

**Edit2:**
The tablet I've got in mind is a Quaduro Flight-Pad Tablet PC

Comment: Clarify what you mean by 'local' application, I presume running on another machine?

Comment: 1 GHz is like saying that your TV's bezel is 3 meters by 2 meters in size.  Sure, it gives us some decent assumptions--it's *unlikely* that you've got only a cell phone-sized screen inside that enormous bezel--but it's not enough information to say for sure.  Model numbers, please!

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: I've previously run XP SP3 on a tablet with those specs and apart from a little sluggishness from time to time it was just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds fine to me. Try [Midori](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php?/pages/midori_summary.html), or [Dillo](http://www.dillo.org/) if even that's too much for it.

Comment: I agree, should be plenty enough to run a lightweight browser.

Answer (score 1):

Processor is: 1.2 GHz C7-M ULV Processor
RAM: 1GB DDR2-400
Chipset: 
  VIA VX700 with integrated VIA UniChrome Pro II IGP Graphics
  Integrated Southbridge with 8-channel HD Audio
  V-Link 533 MB/s bandwidth North/South Bridge interconnect
Display: 7” TFT LCD, native resolution of 1024x600

Answer (score 1):

Chrome/Chromium will work fine. I tried running it on a netbook with 1GiB of RAM underclocked to 1GHz, and it even was not slow.